# Form automatic submit without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I searched a lot of answers on the internet, but none doesn't help me. Also I don't really understand Ajax. 
Everything must happen on this one page without refreshing (until whole form will be submitted).

```
<form id="service" action="" method="post">
    <select name="service" onchange="document.getElementById('service').submit();" name="select">
        <option value="1" <?php if($_POST['service']==1){ print ' selected'; }?>>Opcja1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($_POST['service']==2){ print ' selected'; }?>>Opcja2</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

---

```
if($_POST['service']==1 | empty($_POST['service']) ){
    //other forms and options
    }
elseif($_POST['service']==2){
    //smth
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: **"I don't really understand Ajax"** Well you yourself have stated it, you need to grab an ebook or online video tutorial about AJAX to understand it, no one on SO is supposed to teach you what AJAX is.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola Already submit is automatic when i choose option from dropdown menu. But page is refreshing - what I don't want to.

Comment: This is not ajax it's just javascript which performing submit on change. You should use `jquery ajax ` it's easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to intercept the form submission and have ajax handle posting the data something along these lines is a good start:

```
$('#service select').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "site-to-post-to.php",
      data: $('#service').serialize(),
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
})
```

This will serialize the data in the form and send it via ajax to whatever url you specify.  You'll need to remove the onchange from your html.

Answer (score 0):

To clear a bit of your javascript code use jquery it makes the ajax class quite simpler:

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
```

" Everything must happen on this one page without refreshing" i don't know what you mean by this are you trying to say it will only submit the form with user permission? and that permission is only when the form is completed?
if so you just need to say in the php file that the ajax call is refering to that:

```
if $_GET['form'] == isSafeandCorrect
     echo json_encode('success');
```

and then in your ajax call in the success function(){}

```
.success(function(msh){
     if msg == success
          window.location.href = "yournewPage.php";
 })
```

keep in mind the attribute dataType if not the correct it won't show error
also with ajax calls avoid calling the same page, always a clear php file without html

Comment: Copying and pasting some example from jQuery's website is not helpful.

Comment: he clearly doesn't know all the tools to web development if you want me to do his job he should pay

Answer (score 0):

For flexibility I recommend to write url and method to form, and trigger submit event from children element.
What it gives?
1. one point of form handling
2. call trigger submit event from any child element

here is code:

```js
$(function(){
  
  function handleForm(form, callback) {
    form.on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    
      $.ajax({
        method: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          console.log('sending '+settings.method+' to: '+settings.url);
        }
      })
      .always(callback);
    });
  }

  $('#service select[name="service"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).parent().submit();
  });
  
  handleForm($('#service'), function(response){console.log(response);});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="service" action="/some/uri" method="post">
    <select name="service">
        <option value="1">Opcja1</option>
        <option value="2">Opcja2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice, exactly what I posted before with a bunch of extra fluff.

Comment: thanks @stefan I've upvoted Your answer, but to be honest, I've not copied Your answer. p.s. user3761919 could say same, but not. $.ajax functions parameters are few and there always a way to be interception in our answers. (: